# Root partition failing, usb, ext4, Archlinux

Tags: mount, usb, io, fsck

## Problem:

Installed Archlinux on a USB pen-drive (ext4) about a month ago.
Everything was working fine up until recently. After a while I would not be able to execute commands (except bash built-ins).

```
$ ls
-bash: /usr/bin/ls: Input/output error
$ ls
-bash: ls: command not found
$ bash
Bus error
```

When this happens a reboot usually "fixes" the problem temporarily. Everything would be working again but these errors would come up eventually again. When they do the system becomes unusable and I have to reboot again. This makes it difficult to troubleshoot the issue.

## Tried:

- First backing up all important data
- Booting into a "live usb" and doing `fsck` on the partition in question
- Freeing up some disk space on the partition in question
- Plugging in the USB pen-drive to a different USB port and making sure it's plugged in correctly
- Staying logged in as root to try to peek `echo "$(</proc/kmsg)"` - doesn't work
- Running `dmesg -n err` did produce errors in the VT console eventually but forgot to write them down. Will add them to this post if I see them again and if relevant. I remember it mentioning the journal.

## Ideas:

I remember having similar problems years back when installing Linux on a USB drive. I remember it having something to do with disk caching and the lifespan of the device. Of course this may be about something different.

I was considering doing `dd if=/dev/sdd of=/dev/null` to see if I get any errors. Haven't done that yet but will and will post results - if you think it's relevant.
What I'd like ideally is to:

- Find out what exactly the problem is
- See if I can still save this storage medium
- Prevent this from happening again in the future with another USB drive.
- Check if there's anything I could do to not have to reboot

Let me know if there's anything else I should try and what the most likely explanation could be for what is happening.

**Edit:**
Don't know how relevant this is but I noticed with `iostat` that something is constantly trying to write to the drive every few seconds. Looking into this currently. Apparently it's to do with `/sys/module/workqueue/parameters/power_efficient`

```
6114 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 69.00 % [kworker/u8:6+events_freezable_power_]
7945 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.11 % [kworker/u8:5-events_freezable_power_]
7207 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.01 % [kworker/u8:1-events_freezable_power_]
```

Comment: I think you're on the right path. I think you should try the `dd` command. You may also be able to get the USB drive to execute a self-test using `smartctl`: https://www.smartmontools.org

Comment: Check `dmesg` output when errors start coming. Most USB pen drives are incompatible with `smartctl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input/output errors are always hardware. You may try different USB ports but I assume the stick to be the problem. Maybe after some time when it has got warm.

I suggest to throw away the stick.